# My sliverappbar doesn't expand when i start scrolling back up, it only expands when i get to the top of the list again

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have a nestedsrcollview with a sliverappbar that shrinks when i scroll down as expected but the app bar doesn't expanded when i scroll back up, not until i get to the top(to the first item on the list) and i know this is no right after looking at examples from the docs. It should expand or contract at the moment you start scrolling and not when you're done scrolling up or down

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(//icon),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(//icon),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          //icon,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          //icon,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  final List tabChildren = [
    Child1(

      key: PageStorageKey<String>('1'),
    ),
    Child2(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('2'),
    ),
    Child3(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('3'),
    ),
   Child4(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('4'),
    ),
  ];




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length)

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: NestedScrollView(

        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            new SliverAppBar(


              title: Text(
                'Dummy text',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .title
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,

              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(

                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: myTabs,
              ),
            ),

          ];
        },

        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [

            SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child: 

                tabChildren[0], // listView

            ),
            SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child: 

                tabChildren[1], // listView


            ),
            SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child: 
                tabChildren[2], // listView


            ),
            SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child:  

              tabChildren[3], // listView

            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following attributes.

```
snap: true,
floating: true
```

Example:

```
new SliverAppBar(

              title: Text(
                'Dummy text',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .title
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              floating: true,
              snap: true,
              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(

                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: myTabs,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Two attributes control the SliverAppBar's Action. `pinned` & `floating`

You have set both the `pinned` and `floating` set to true, even though it is not wrong, you can never see the actual Sliver Motion when both are set to true.

To actually get what you are calling as "expanded effect" set only `floating` to true. If that is not what you are looking for, probably a Image or GIF as to what is your expected output will help in achieving the correct code.

Comment: The example with floating and pinned set to true is the behaviour i want but in my case the appbar doesn't expand until it gets to list item 1

Comment: You are trying to achieve the type 4 in the link you sent? Or which one? Possible to share the working GIF of your app?

Comment: Yes, type 4. It's floating and pinned properties are the same as mine